# Как сгенерировать рандомное число с заданной суммой цифр в нем

Tags: c

Как сгенерировать рандомное число с заданной суммой цифр в нем

Comment: Если совсем по-честному — или сгенерировать все возможные, или перенумеровать :), и выбирать из набора случайным образом... *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Читайте нужное количество байт из `/dev/random`, зачем париться?

Comment: @Harry Прочитал ваш комментарий, и вспомнил про метод сортировки через `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Есть ограничения на диапазон? Какое распределение? А то зададите сумму - единица, подходит `10^k`, `k` - любое целое неотрицательное. А их бесконечно много. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do {
     a = rand() % 900 + 100;
    if ((a / 100) + ((a / 10) % 10) + (a % 10) == S) // проверка или сумма цифр в сгенерированном числе = S
    {                                                // если равно, то выводится это число, значение k увеличивается на 1
                                                     // если сумма цифр не равна S , генерируется новое число, значение k не меняется
        printf("%d ", a);                           // цикл будет выполняться пока k не приобретет значение K
        k++;
    }
} while (k <= K);
```

Comment: S - сумма цифр в числе, вводит пользователь
K – количество чисел, вводит пользователь
Диапазон от 100 до 999

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать так (псевдокод)

```
искомое число = 0

пока сумма > 0:
  определить случайное число от 0 до min(сумма, 9)
  дополнить разряд в искомом числе - искомое число = искомое число * 10 + определённое случайное число
  уменьшить сумму на найденное случайное число
```

есть один недостаток - если случайное число постоянно будет выдавать 0 (вероятность события стремится к 0, но оно есть для генераторов истинных случайных чисел), то число вы никогда не сгенерируете :)

Comment: А будет ли это число истинно случайным? Не будет ли какого-то смещения?

Comment: это конечно вопрос, дело в том, что можно подсчитать все возможные варианты формирования числа с суммой цифр равной заданной и выбрать среди этих вариантов - тут будет истинное линейное распределение, но есть еще 1 проблема - любое такое число может быть ДОПОЛНЕНО НЕОГРАНИЧЕННЫМ КОЛ-ВОМ НУЛЕЙ - и вот это уже проблема :) т.е. надо еще и размер числа ограничивать, а вообще можно проМонтеКарлить :) - генерировать случайное число и потом считать числа пока не найдем первое удовлетворяющее нас число, но это будет очень долго и неэффективно

Comment: О нулях я и не подумал, а это же проблема!..